# If $G$ has a non-trivial center then $G/Z(G)$ has a trivial center.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that

> If $G$ has a non-trivial center then $G/Z(G)$ has a trivial center.

**My try**:

Let $G/Z(G)$ have a non-trivial center.Let $a+Z(G)\in Z(G/Z(G))$ where $a\notin Z(G)$.Then $(a+Z(G))(b+Z(G))=(b+Z(G))(a+Z(G))$

$\implies ab-ba\in Z(G) 
\forall (b+Z(G))\in G/Z(G)$

Also we have a $c(\neq e)\in Z(G)$.

How to arrive at a contradiction from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $G=D_4$.

$G/Z(G)$ is of order four and hence abelian.

Comment: what will be $Z(G)$ here/

Comment: $Z(D_4)$ has two elements. rotations by 0 and 180 degree

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for example if G is non commutative and nilpotent